# code coverage in visual studio 2008 pro

Tags: visual-studio-2008, code-coverage

I am writing some unit tests using visual studio 2008 professional edition.
I learned that visual studio has a built in code coverage utility however it seems that this feature is not available with my version of visual studio. 
Do someone know which versions of visual studio 2008 include the code coverage utility ?

Tzachi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code coverage is available in VS2008 Team Suite (only) or VS2010 Premium or Ultimate.

Comment: University students can get it for free from MSDNAA. I have an original copy too :)